# TS2307: Cannot find module 'playwright' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: package, mocha.js, nvm, playwright

I am trying to run tests on my new workstation. The tests use Playwright and Mocha. Downloaded the repository, performed

```
yarn install
```

installed Playwright and Mocha globally

```
yarn global add mocha
yarn global add playwright
```

But when I run the tests as follows

```
.\node_modules\.bin\mocha --require ts-node/register tests/*.spec.ts --reporter-options "reportDir=reports,reportFilename=tests-report" --url=http://localhost/
```

the following error is thrown:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'playwright' or its corresponding
> type declarations.
>
> 5 } from 'playwright'
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ```
> at createTSError (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:434:12)
> at reportTSError (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:438:19)
> at getOutput (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:578:36)
> at Object.compile (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:775:32)
> at Module.m._compile (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:858:43)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
> ```

I also tried uninstalling yarn and reinstalling it to make sure yarn is installed after nvm (heard it may cause issues), but still getting this error.

What else can be done here? Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Installing packages globally is not recommended, when you work with multiple projects which use e.g. different Playwright versions, you'll run into issues. So installing it locally is the way to go.

Comment: Understand, but I tried installing the packages globally out of desperation, as running just yarn install would also not let me run the tests with the same error.